# Sharepoint: Office Documents can only be uploaded; not opened and saved

Tags: sharepoint

I had two clients with a save issue in SharePoint.
When they try to save they would get a a very generic error: "Document Could not be saved"

The only way they could get them into SharePoint was by:

1. Saving to local File System
2. Using the *Upload* option from the SharePoint menu

**Configurations**

- Client 1:  Vista and Office 2007
- Client 2:  XP and Office 2003

I was able to fix client 1 by having him Map a Network Drive to the Sharepoint Site.

After mapping the network drive, somehow the OS magically knew about the SharePoint documents folder and he was able to save.

I'm not having the same luck with Client 2.

It won't even let me map the network drive.  I get an error (one that I did not take a screenshot of and don't remember the exact wording...sorry).  but it was an error trying to map the network drive to the SharePoint site.

So, after some Googling, I had him go to Windows Update and download all the latest patches for his OS.

He claims he did, but is still getting the problem.

Before I do another WebEx and start taking stabs in the dark to try and fix him, I was wondering if any veteran SharePoint users have run into this same issue and what they did to fix.

Or, is there some OS setting I should be looking at that needs to be toggled/modified.

I can access his SharePoint site just fine from several PCs and make modifications and save as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the Microsoft Office Diagnostics?

Start --> Microsoft Office --> Microsoft Office Tools --> Microsoft Office Diagnostics

Let that scan and repair any issues it finds and see if that helps.  That tool has fixed similar issues for me many times.

Comment: It's Office 2003, so I can't do that one :(

I think I'll have to try Detect and Repair from the Help menu next time I'm on conference with him.

ty though!